# Error in displaying map with direction

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am creating a wp8 application , and I am using this html code to display 2 pushpins and the directions between them but the problem is that the directions are displayed without the map (on the emulater the html page is all displayed without problem).

There is my Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Amex</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var rendererOptions = {
  draggable: false
  };
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  var ksa = new google.maps.LatLng(24.7116667, 46.7241667);

  function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
  zoom: 7,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: ksa
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));

  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
  computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);
  });

  calcRoute();
  }

  function calcRoute() {

  var request = {
  origin: new google.maps.LatLng(23.7116667, 45.7241667),
  destination: new google.maps.LatLng(20.7116667, 45.7241667),
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
  });
  }

  function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
      total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000.
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + " km";
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80%"></div>
<div id="directionsPanel" style="width:100%;height 20%;font-family:arial">
<p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>

</div>
</body>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What emulator are you talking about?

Comment: @geocodezip Windows Phone 8 emulator

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution It is just need to replace this

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80%"></div>
```

by this

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px; height:480px"></div>
```